# how to call class without declaring it in constructor angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2, nfc

I am trying to use NFC module of Ionic 2. This is my code:

**nfc-scan.ts:**

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';
    import {NFC, Ndef} from '@ionic-native/nfc';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
        selector: 'nfc-scan',
        templateUrl: 'nfc-scan.html',
    })
    export class NfcScan {
        @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
NFC: NFC;

    constructor(public platform: Platform,
                    public navCtrl: NavController,
                    public navParams: NavParams,
        ) {

        }

    // NFC Scanning
        checkNFC()
        {
            this.NFC.enabled()
                .then(() => {
                    this.addListenNFC();
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }
    }
```

**nfs-scan.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <button on (click)="checkNFC()">Scan NFC</button>
</ion-content>
```

When I run the application, I get the error:

> Property 'enabled' does not exist on type 'typeof NFC'.

I know I am not declaring NFC in the constructor of nfc-scan.ts. But when I do so, the page won't even load altogether.

Comment: NFC: NFC may cause this one. You are declarin a variable same name with class change it to nfc : NFC or another name you like then try.

Comment: @0m3rF I did that already but no luck.

Comment: hmmm... as far as i know you should declare it inside constructor. Even services, which is Injectable, work like that. Are you sure that declaring NFC inside constructor causes to not loading page?

Comment: Yes. As soon I add it in constructor, the page doesn't load at all. No errors are thrown either. So don't know what's going on.

Comment: It is interesting that you are getting this error as soon as it loads. You dont even click on that button 0.o. Well i couldn't find any solution sorry.. Good luck on that ^_^

Comment: Thank you anyways for your input. I'll post the solution here once I find it.

Comment: Probably your are using Lazy loading and forgot to add the NFC module in the app.module.ts file ? Or your need to upgrade the nfc module and cordova version, only using ionic 2? Upgrade to 3 and try.

Comment: The NFC module is present in app.module.ts and we have to use ionic 2 as a part of project requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally manage to find a solution to this problem. It turns out that it's true you can't use a class without declaring it in the constructor of the class where you want to use it.

In my case, the issue was, that I was running the app in my machine's (Macbook) browser, whereas NFC plugin can only be instantiated on a phone that supports NFC (Like camera plugin). Having said that, Ionic now provides ability to mock plugins in a way so that you can use them in your machine's browser.

> To use an Ionic Native plugin in the browser and ionic serve session,
>   you just need to extend the original plugin class and override the
>   methods you’d like to mock.

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/browser.html

Hope it helps someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually see an output on the console, when the page is not loading. Make sure to use private nfc : NFC in the constructor;